# How can I align rectangle instances to sphere?

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector

[image]

My set up for the geometry nodes

[image]

I want the rectangles that are instanced on the cube to point towards the UV sphere. How can I change the rotation of the rectangles such that it points towards the sphere?

I've tried to use the Align Euler to Vector node, however I can not figure out how the node works. Is there anyway I can go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this node setup here:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly what I needed!

Comment: you are welcome